# Git Submodule Command not executing properly

Tags: git, build, submodule

I am trying to run this command:

```
$git submodule init
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Why am I getting this error. I am trying to set up ActionBarSherlock, but I can not get past the first command. I need ABS for building K-9 Mail. The instructions are here: https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/wiki/BuildingK9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is accurate. You're getting it because you're running `git submodule init` outside a git repository. Based on the (admittedly sort of vague) directions under "Building with IntelliJ IDEA" on that link, try cloning k9's source from github and downloading ActionBarSherlock first.

Comment: Yes, I realized that latter. It was because I didn't clone the repository, I downloaded the ZIP archive. I'll accept your answer, as it was the problem.